# Closing front end from within

Tags: front-end, initialization

Based on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/655/204) I'd like to close the mathematica front end without the nagging dialog boxes that follow.

Why am I trying to do this?

I have a bash script which is such:

```
#!/bin/bash

mathematica bfile01.nb
pid1=$(pgrep mathematica)
kill -9 $pid1

! [ -z `pidof mathematica` ] || mathematica bfile02.nb
pid2=$(pgrep mathematica)
kill -9 $pid2

! [ -z `pidof mathematica` ] || mathematica bfile03.nb
```

So this is just a serial execution of several mathematica files, each of which has an [initialization cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9484/204) in it.

I find that unless I close the front end, the next file doesn't launch and killing the process in the unix terminal didn't quite help (very strange as this only happens with mathematica)

So any thoughts or ideas?

## Edit 2: Using a mathematica script file

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/test3.m) is a mathematica file that I converted into a script:
When I chmod it and run it, I get a bunch of error messages which don't allow my figures to be saved from the Plot3D or ContourPlot.

If you try to run the file attached (test3.m), you would want to change the file save path, `Export` in the last line of the file.

### Error messages:

```
> General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed
> during this calculation.
```

## Edit 3:

In the test3.m file, I made the following changes:

Changed `hSol =` to `hSol[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ]` ([file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/test3.m) has been uploaded).

This has changed the error messages that I get to:

```
> Part::partw: Part 3 of InterpolatingFunctionDomain[hSol] does not
> exist.
> 
> Set::shape: Lists {TMin, TRup} and
> InterpolatingFunctionDomain[hSol][[3]] are not the same shape.
> 
> Set::shape: Lists {nX, nY, nT} and {} are not the same shape.
```

Clearly, when run as a mathematica notebook, I never got these errors.

## Edit 4:

I seem to have corrected my errors after Ruebenko's last comment.

the new file is attached [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/test5.m).

Heres the issue that I had:

Once the package was created (.m file), when opened in a text editor, all the lines were commented out with (**) which I don't know why.

However, getting rid of the comments also uncommented some text that I had previously commented so as to not use. That resulted in error messages.

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: ref/program/MathematicaScript

Comment: @ruebenko It seems to lack proper documentation though.

Comment: seems fully documented to me. This is not a Mathematica function. Have a look in the more into and the tutorial tutorial/MathematicaScripts.

Comment: @ruebenko Hmmm... this needs some consideration. Thank you. I didn't quite understand that what you included in your comment was the actual path to the tutorial. Will look into that. However, what if I am compelled to use bash scripting exclusively without turning my mathematica file into a script? (Just playing devils adv.)

Comment: @ruebenko So, the shabang or the preamble to include: `#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script` is it included in the .m file? And also, is this .m file run from the terminal window in linux or from within the mathkernel? Because if it is run from within the mathkernel, it probably defeats my purpose. I'd be able to run only one .m file at a time.

Comment: ,with the preamble you can run that file like any other script file. It's like a bash, just that the interpreter is Mathematica Kernel.

Comment: @ruebenko I checked my file again and I saw that everything in my `m-file` was commented out. I uncommented it and things worked well. However, when I try this with a more complete program like in **edit 2**, I get a bunch of error messages. What gives?

Comment: For me this gives messages in a regular FE.

Comment: @ruebenko I am sorry but your comment was very cryptic. What does "regular FE" mean? Also, I changed a couple things. I included `hSol[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] = h /. NDSolve[{Bo, \[Epsilon], K1, \[Delta], Bi, m, ...` and got a bunch of other errors. Edit 3.

Comment: Seems to be an error in the mathematica file. I'll try to work on it and put it up again!

Comment: When I tried your file from Edit 2 it did not work in Mathematica. No script involved at this step. FE is short for FrontEnd.

Comment: @ruebenko Hi, check edit 4. I think I figured it out.

Comment: Excellent. Have fun with the scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try MathematicaScrip which was made for exactly this purpose.

Documentation for that is [ref/program/MathematicaScript](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/MathematicaScript.html) and perhaps [tutorial/MathematicaScripts](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaScripts.html)

Comment: Done! `:)` Hopefully I won't run into too many issues. But obv. I'd still be interested in the front end tokens

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at: [Programmatically quitting the FrontEnd or running without one?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8392/programmatically-quitting-the-frontend-or-running-without-one)

I asked some similar questions and the answers have some good strategies to do this although most of them as workarounds outside of the Mathematica front end.

A simple but key thing, adding

```
NotebookSave[]
```

to the end of your initializations cell can avoid some of the problems with pop up dialog boxes.

You may find:

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["QuitKernel"]
```

useful.

But I did not find a way to quit Mathematica with a FrontEndToken even if it directly followed saving the notebook, because unfortunately, executing a single command changes the notebook's state, which then prompts one to save the notebook on exit.

*A nice to have -- running a command in a sandbox that wouldn't affect the Front End''s state.*

No clue how to do it, but it could prove useful.

In my application I eventually ran a script on a timer and had to gauge when the notebook completed the processing it needed.

One final thought/question.  Does your application require the front end to run?  You can run the kernel even multiple kernels for parallel processing without a front end.

Some potentially useful links:

- [Running Mathematica without the Notebook interface](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Mathematica.html)
- [running mathematica notebooks without interface](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/msg00603.html)
- [Manipulating the Front End from the Kernel](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingTheFrontEndFromTheKernel.html)

Comment: Will read all this and see what seems to do the trick. And then I'll include that here! Thanks!

Comment: You could use `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], "ClosingSaveDialog" -> False]` after saving to avoid the save prompt.

Comment: @SimonWoods -- Great idea. I didn't know about the setting. Thanks.

Comment: `FrontEndTokenExecute["QuitKernel"]`  Didn't close the notebook...

Comment: Including the following `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], "ClosingSaveDialog" -> False]
FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"];` still gave rise to the dialog box `:(`