# Changing fonts for an entire notebook

Tags: formatting

The very nice answer to this question [How to close the front end so I can clear all Global variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/654) explain how to create a palette to change locally a font and its characteristics.  Could it be possible to add a checkbox to apply the change to the complete Notebook?

Comment: As much for me. Sorry

Comment: Are you sure the link is correct now?  That question seems barely related at best.

Comment: Changing the fonts for an entire notebook is boring when you want to make some test. I was wondering if one could not have a mechanism  like  the one referenced to facilitate some experiments